# Ubuntu boots into Grub Rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

Before writing about the problem, I would like to tell that I have tried several solutions from various websites including the following (and other sources from AskUbuntu), thus this is not a duplicate:

1. Link http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
2. Link https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux

After installing updates today my Ubuntu 16.04 boots into grub rescue. There I have used the `ls` command to find the partitions and it lists:
(hd0), (hd1), (hd1, gpt3), (hd1, gpt2), (hd1, gpt1)

I have searched those for the root file system (see Link 2), but I cannot find it. If I insert a live-CD I can find the partition with Ubuntu, so the hard drive is clearly intact, but I cannot access it from the grub terminal. So using the `ls` command I either get "unknown filesystem" or the content of the partition is not what I'm looking for. Thus, I cannot finish the tutorial in Link 2.

I have also tried to reinstall grub from a Live-CD. This does not work, because the partition is encrypted (LUK). It also does not work if the same partition is mounted unencrypted.

Any ideas? It is very important for me to get access to my files, because my master thesis is there. I have tried to manually rescue the encrypted home folder. This did not work, I get a ton of errors.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Just FYI, duplicates only work within this site; duping can't be done beyond Ask Ubuntu.  But thanks for including the links for reference.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private` from live CD? (Check out [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/))

Comment: Yes, I did but for some reason the file is not found although I can see it in Nautilus.